# Length of sides of a triangle and area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, polygons

Let $T$ be a triangle with sides of length $a,b,c$ and $T'$ a triangle with sides of length $a',b',c'$. If $a<a'$ and $b<b'$ and $c<c'$, is it true $Area(T)<Area(T')$?

I've tried to use Heron's formula, but I wasn't able to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's wrong! Try, $a=b=c=1$ and $a'=b'=100$ and $c'\rightarrow200^-$.

For example, $c'=199.9999999$ is valid.